# How to find reason for orphaned packages in apt-get autoremove?

Tags: apt, package-management

In general, `apt-get autoremove` removes packages that have been installed as a dependency of some other package which is now no longer installed. I noticed that my list of orphaned packages includes things like `emacs24` and `tmux`, which I definitely want to keep. Is it possible to find out which other (now missing) package was responsible for installing them in the first place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Automatically:

One of the solutions is to use `aptitude`, first install it:

```
sudo apt install aptitude
```

Now to find out why a package has been installed on your Ubuntu you can run:

```
aptitude why pkgname
```

However note that:

> The dependency that aptitude produced in this case is only a suggestion. This is because no package currently installed on this computer depends on or recommends the "pkgname".

Also:

> `aptitude why` does not perform full dependency resolution; it only displays
>   direct relationships between packages.

In conclusion if you can't find a related package, then there is a high chance that this package has been installed as a dependency or recommendation of on of the other packages that is going to be removed using `apt autoremove`, or somehow is related to this chain.

#### Manually

First let's produce a situation then try to find out why a package has been installed, I first installed `vlc` on my system:

```
sudo apt install vlc
```

after that I only remove the `vlc` itself using `sudo apt remove vlc`, now if I run `sudo apt autoremove` I'll get:

```
libqt5x11extras5 vlc-bin vlc-plugin-qt ...
```

let's first check one of them  using `aptitude`:

```
$ aptitude why libqt5x11extras5
aptitude why libqt5x11extras5
i   xorg      Depends  xterm | x-terminal-emulator
p   qterminal Provides x-terminal-emulator
```

however the other one because of a direct dependency chain will work fine:

```
$ aptitude why vlc-bin
c   vlc      Depends  vlc-bin
```

pay attention to the `c` it means that the package was deleted but its configuration files still lives on my system so there is a high chance (in this case 100%) that `vlc-bin` was installed by `vlc`.

Now let's back to our job and findout why `libqt5x11extras5` lives on our Ubuntu:

```
$ apt-cache rdepends libqt5x11extras5 | xargs dpkg -l |& grep -e '^i' -e '^rc'
```

using `apt-cache rdepends` I'm looking for all packages which has dependency on `libqt5x11extras5`, then I'm looking for the ones which are installed or was installed on my system using `dpkg` with the combination of `grep`, the result is:

```
ii  libqt5x11extras5
ii  vlc-plugin-qt
```

see? we found out that this package was related to another package that is in our `autoremove` list: `vlc-plugin-qt`, at the end:

```
$ aptitude why vlc-plugin-qt
c   vlc
```

and we came back to the `vlc`.